# LSTM based policy in stable baselines3 model

Tags: reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines

I am trying to make a PPO model using the stable-baselines3 library. I want to use a policy network with an LSTM layer in it. However, I can't find such a possibility on the library's website although it exists on the previous version of stable-baselines here https://stable-baselines.readthedocs.io/en/master/modules/policies.html#stable_baselines.common.policies.MlpLstmPolicy.

Does this possibility exist in stable-baselines3 (not stable-baselines)? if not, is there any other possibility I can do this? Thanx.

Answer (score 3):

From the migration doc.

https://stable-baselines3.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/migration.html

> Breaking Changes¶
>
> LSTM policies (`MlpLstmPolicy`, `CnnLstmPolicy`) are not supported for
> the time being (see PR #53 for a recurrent PPO implementation)

Answer (score 3):

Currently this functionality does not exist on stable-baselines3.

However, on their contributions repo ([stable-baselines3-contrib](https://github.com/Stable-Baselines-Team/stable-baselines3-contrib/tree/master)) they have an experimental version of PPO with LSTM policy. I have not tried it myself, but according to [this pull request](https://github.com/Stable-Baselines-Team/stable-baselines3-contrib/pull/53) it works.

You can find it on the `feat/ppo-lstm` branch, which may get merged onto `master` soon.